# Custom replace function with parameter not working

Tags: jquery, function

I created the following function

```
function myFunction(x) {
  x = x.replace(/Ö/g, "&Ouml;");
}
```

This does not work when I call it:

```
var myVar = "some text containing a Ö";
myFunction(myVar);
```

But when using it without the function, it works:

```
var myVar = "some text containing a Ö";
myVar = myVar.replace(/Ö/g, "&Ouml;");
```

Am I missing something?

Thank you.

Comment: check my answer you have to add a return statement to the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are just replacing the character but not returning the result string from the function you have to use a return statement in the function like below -

```js
  
    function myFunction(x) {
       x = x.replace(/Ö/g, "&Ouml;");
       return x;
    }
    
    var myVar = "some text containing a Ö";
    var result = myFunction(myVar);
    
    console.log(result); //some text containing a &Ouml;
```

Here is a working fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/wf0czg3t/2/

Comment: Hi, @Niladri , thanks for your answer. I see in the fiddle that it is working, but for some reason, it does not work when I call it. Even with return.

Comment: @SergeInácio what is the issue?can you post your code where you are calling it?

Comment: I am calling it just after the creation of the variable. And the function is created before the variable.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to do a separate variable. it works :) thanks

Answer (score 2):

Add return statement in your function

```
function myFunction(x) {
  x = x.replace(/Ö/g, "&Ouml;");

  return x;
}
```

fiddle:

```js
function myFunction(x) {
  x = x.replace(/Ö/g, "&Ouml;");
  
  return x;
}

var myVar = "some text containing a Ö";
var result = myFunction(myVar);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Hi @Nirali, does not seem to work with me. Strange, but I see that your example works.